# PHP LDAP Operational Attribute Queries

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to view LDAP operational attributes such as nsAccountLookup, pwdAccountLockedTime, etc.

When I look at the attributes being returned I don't see those in the list. Below is the code I'm using...any suggestions?

```
$ds = ldap_connect( $ldaphost, $ldapport )
$dn="ou=People,o=companyName";
$filterUID = "(uid=$uid)";
$result = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filterUID);
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ds, $result);
$lock= $entries[0]["nsAccountLock"][0];
```

To be a bit more clear - how would one view more operational attributes?

Comment: Suggestion: The uid is invalid.

Comment: @hakre The uid is my uid - other attributes return fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify attributes you want to get from LDAP as fourth argument in `ldap_search()` function:

```
$attributes = array('nsAccountLock');
$result = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filterUID, $attributes);
```

Comment: Perfect! I made the mistake of assuming that not specifying attributes would return all available ones. Thanks for fixing my stupid assumption :)

Answer (score 0):

Operational attribute must be explicitly requested in the list of requested attributes and the directory server must be configured to allow them to be returned.